# Mistake in do Carmo's book Riemannian geometry?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading do Carmo's book Riemannian geometry and at the chapter 5 Jacobi fields, is this proposition.

[image]

My question is where is $a$ in the proof? At the first equal sign we should have $\frac{1}{a}$ in front of $v$ and $w.$ More over in the end we obtain that $\frac{D\overline{J}}{dt}(0)=\frac{w}{a}$ which dose not agree with $\frac{DJ}{dt}(0)=w.$ I'm missing out on something? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I do agree with you the proof seems wrong. One possible correction is defining $v'(0)$ as $aw$ instead of $w$.

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

Comment: @Hugocito If you want, you can write that as an answer with details. For me is ok.

Comment: Sorry, I'm too lazy! If you are convinced it's ok then I'm fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks again!

Comment: I just got to this page in the book, had the same puzzlement, and found this question. However, I'm wondering why not simply set $v(0)=v$, $v'(0)=w$, and $f(t,s) = exp_p(tv(s))$.